# How to validate a local XML document against a local XSD schema - Issues with ValidationEventHandler

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema

I am attempting to simply validate a XML document that gets created by my program (output.xml) against a locally stored XSD schema called myConfig.config.xsd.  Firstly this won't run because the Validation event handler I attempt to create returns the error "'System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'" which makes sense but the tutorial I reference below does exactly this. Furthermore, the xsd file I reference is local and the other tutorials seem to reference XSDs with online namespaces. For mine I just put "schema" as the namespace; is this ok?

Here is my method:

```
public void Validate()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add("schema", "myConfig.config.xsd"); //!!Here is where I just put "schema" as the namespace
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallback);

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("output.xml", settings);
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(reader);
            ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler); 
            //^Here is the problem line that won't let me build this program

            document.Validate(eventHandler);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    private static void ValidationCallback(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            Console.WriteLine("\tWarning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred." + args.Message);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\tValidation error: " + args.Message);
    }
```

I am trying to use this guide to help me do this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162371(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example actually has a method called `ValidationEventHandler`.  You don't.  Change your `eventHandler` assignment to use your actual event handler method:

```
ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallback);
```

You can also use the implicit conversion:

```
ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = ValidationCallback;
```

Or omit the local variable entirely:

```
document.Validate(ValidationCallback);
```